# How to get value of a textbox in the same row as the button that will perform the function?

Tags: javascript, html

I know it's something like:

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var val = table.rows[currentRow].cells[1].children[0].value;
```

I am unsure of what to put between the hard brackets after rows. (current row being what I don't know what to put)

I want to be able to click a button that when clicked, the textbox in the same row will return the value of the textbox. The textbox and both the button were dynamically created with Javascript. I am really mainly just concerned with how to get the value of the textbox in this current row.

The "///" is what I don't know what to put.

```
var total = 0;

  function frenchBread(x){
      var table = document.getElementById("orderTable");
      var row = table.insertRow(0);

      var rem = document.createElement("button");
      var name = document.createTextNode("Remove");
      rem.appendChild(name);  
      rem.onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("orderTable").deleteRow(this);
        x.disabled = false;
        document.getTotal.total.value = document.getTotal.total.value - (9 * table.rows[///].cells[1].children[0].value);
      }

      var num = document.createElement("input");
      num.size = 2;

      num.onchange = function(){

        var table = document.getElementById("orderTable");
        var amount = 0;
        var tot = 0;
        for(var x = 0; x < table.rows.length; x++){
         amount = amount + table.rows[x].cells[1].children[0].value;
        }
        tot = amount * 9;
        document.getTotal.total.value = tot;
      }

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

        cell1.innerHTML = "French Bread";
        cell2.appendChild(num);
        cell3.appendChild(rem);
        x.disabled = true;
        num.value = 1;
        total = total + 9;
        document.getTotal.total.value = total;

  }


<table>
      <tr>
          <td><button type = "button" onclick = "frenchBread(this)">>img src = "FrenchBread.png"></button></td>
       </tr>
</table>

<table id = "orderTable">
            </table>
```

I would also like to know how to add the values of the textboxes in the for loop. The numbers are just appending to each other. For example, when one box says 1 and the other says 2, instead of adding to become three, it becomes 12.

```
num.onchange = function(){

        var table = document.getElementById("orderTable");
        var amount = 0;
        var tot = 0;
        for(var x = 0; x < table.rows.length; x++){
         amount = amount + table.rows[x].cells[1].children[0].value;
        }
        tot = amount * 9;
        document.getTotal.total.value = tot;
      }
```

Comment: Show the HTML you have.

Comment: instead of doing it that way... can you give a class to each of the relevant table cells (eg `<td class="description">input goes here</td><td class="action_button">button is in this cell</td>"` then you can use `$('.action_button').siblings('.description')` or similar to fetch it (you may need to de-arrrayify it)